# PHPExcel - Why is setTitle so time-consuming

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am creating an Excel-file/workbook with salary calculations using PHPExcel. Every employee's calculation is done in a separate worksheet.

Renaming the worksheets works just fine, but it is so time-consuming!

By putting microsecond-timestamps through the code, I have seen that the testserver spends 40-50 seconds (!) running this line 150 times:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle($name);
```

So when doing the calculations on a web-server, the server "gives up" and gives a 503-message before finishing the workbook....

I have tried using the latest version of PHPExcel without any improvement. Does anyone have a better solution for renaming the sheets?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need renaming the sheets 150 times? The sheet names are or at least maybe parts of references in formulas. For example: `=Sheet1!A1*123`. So if you are renaming a sheet, all references to this sheet in all formulas must be updated.

Comment: @AxelRichter: Sorry for mixing the excel-terms. I have edited the question to be clearer.

When creating a new sheet with $objPHPExcel->createSheet(NULL, $number);, it's called Worksheet 1, Worksheet 2 and so on. I need to rename each of these to the name of the employee. So accounting fast can find the calculations they are looking for. And when there are 150 employees, the setTitle needs to be done 150 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is 4 months old, but I had to resolve an issue with PHPExcel timing out when exporting data in a spreadsheet and I discovered that, unless overridden, `setTitle()` will call `PHPExcel_ReferenceHelper::updateNamedFormulas()`, which then scans every cell in your worksheets to see if it is a cell that is of type `PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_FORMULA`. This means that if you are iterating through worksheets and setting a title for each, it will scan for formula cells in an ever increasing document.

The solution in this case was to make sure to pass `false` as the second parameter for `setTitle()`.

ie.

```
$foo->setTitle( 'foo title', false );
```

See the definition of the method for more info here: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Worksheet.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and a much better solution than I came up with. I recon this would be the best solution for my question :)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not good practice, but commenting out this section in the function setTitle in PHPExcel's Worksheet.php (line 870-878):

```
 if ($this->parent && $this->parent->getCalculationEngine()) {
            // New title
            $newTitle = $this->getTitle();
            $this->parent->getCalculationEngine()
                ->renameCalculationCacheForWorksheet($oldTitle, $newTitle);
            if ($updateFormulaCellReferences) {
                PHPExcel_ReferenceHelper::getInstance()->updateNamedFormulas($this->parent, $oldTitle, $newTitle);
            }
        }
```

made the 150 setTitle actions, go from 45 seconds to 0.03, and I can't see the difference in the result.